# Python: Passing socket by reference

Tags: python, sockets, scope

I am new to python and I am having to code my 1st task in python. I promise that I will learn it inside out after I finish this but I need your help now.

My code is currently looks like this:

```
comSocket.send("\r")
sleep(1)
comSocket.send("\r")
sleep(2)
comSocket.settimeout(8)
try:
   comSocket.recv(256)
except socket.timeout:
   errorLog("[COM. ERROR] Station took too long to reply. \n")
   comSocket.shutdown(1)
   comSocket.close()
   sys.exit(0)

comSocket.send("\r\r")
sleep(2)
comSocket.settimeout(8)
try:
   comSocket.recv(256)
except socket.timeout:
   errorLog("[COM. ERROR] Station took too long to reply. \n")
   comSocket.shutdown(1)
   comSocket.close()
   sys.exit(0)
```

`errorLog` is another method. I want to rewrite this code by making a new method so that I can pass the `message`, reference to the `socket` and then `return` what I receive from the socket.

Any help?

Thank you :)

Comment: `\r\r` is a message :) Message would be a string of any length.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Comment: I know how to define functions/methods. I am wondering about passing `socket` as a references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be

```
def socketCom(comSocket, length, message, time):
    comSocket.send(message)
    comSocket.settimeout(8)
    if (time != 0):
        sleep(time)
    try:
        rawData = comSocket.recv(length)
    except socket.timeout:
        errorLog("[COM. ERROR] Station took too long to reply. \n")
        comSocket.shutdown(1)
        comSocket.close()
        sys.exit(0)

    return rawData
```

Answer (score 3):

A guess at what you're trying for:

```
def send_and_receive(message, socket):
    socket.send(message)
    return socket.recv(256) # number is timeout
```

then put your `try:except:` around your call to this method.

Answer (score 1):

You should do a class to manage your errors and that class needs to extend the one you are using for the instance of comSocket, inside that class you put your errorLog function.
Something like this:

```
class ComunicationSocket(socket):
    def errorLog(self, message):
        # in this case, self it's an instance of your object comSocket, 
        # therefore your "reference"
        # place the content of errorLog function
        return True # Here you return what you received from socket
```

Now with this only what you have to do its instantiate ComunicationSocket:

```
comSocket = ComunicationSocket()
try:
    comSocket.recv(256)
except socket.timeout:
    # Uses the instance of comSocket to log the error
    comSocket.errorLog("[COM. ERROR] Station took too long to reply. \n")
    comSocket.shutdown(1)
    comSocket.close()
    sys.exit(0)
```

Hope that helped, you didn't post the content of your function error log, so I placed a comment where you should put it. This is one way of doing things. Hope that helps.

Comment: Oh, you can use decorators too, let me know if my suggestion helped or we can try something else.